# list pages using page.php and NOT page-{slug}.php

Tags: wp-query, page-template, wp-list-pages

I made a view templates for specific slugs

- page1-220 use page.php
- contact uses page-contact.php
- service uses
  page-service.php

Now I want to list the pages with their templates on a "overview" page with page-overview.php template... .

I tried this:

```
<?php $args = array(
'post_type' => 'page', /* or just 'post' */
'posts_per_page' => -1,

 );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$i=1;
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<p>'; 
    echo $i . '. ';
    the_title();
    echo ' - ';
    echo get_page_template(); 
    echo '</p>';
    $i++;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```

get_page_template() allways returns the path to page-overview.php.

Wonder what I am missing here. I wonder if there is a way to get a list of ids, using the page.php template.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: get_page_template() returns the current page template.  you need get_page_template_slug( $id )  to get the template of $id post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/), but you need to request the [`get_page_template_slug`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template_slug) first.

So that would look like:

```
get_template_part( get_page_template_slug( get_the_ID() ) );
```

in lieu of

```
echo get_page_template();
```

And no need to echo it, it returns the template already printed.